# ASP.NET runtime is deriving the autogenerated class for view (.cshtml) from WebPage instead of WebViewPage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I am getting this issue that auto generating class for view (.cshtm file) is being derived from System.Web.WebPages.WebPage
instead of System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage. This is despite of pageBaseType clearly defined in Views\Web.config as below

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    ....
```

The autogenerated class looks like below

```
    public class _Page_Views_Home_MyHomeView_cshtml : System.Web.WebPages.WebPage {
```

Below is how MyHomeView.cshtml is defined

```
    @model string
    @{
        Layout = null;
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>MyHome
         @Model
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div> 
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The Root/Web.config file adds entry for System.Web.Mvc as below

```
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

I have no as to clue why ASP.NET runtime is deriving the autogenerated class from WebPage instead of WebViewPage.
 I am getting the error

> error CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context.

Which I think is due to incorrect base class for our view.
 If someone has any idea on this please suggest.